# Why is my input validation function not working? (C++)

Tags: c++, validation

I'm writing a program that calculates the cost of a purchase based on user input. If the user uses negative or otherwise invalid values for price and quantity the program should print an error and ask again.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool validatePrice(const string& str) {
    if (str.find_first_not_of("0123456789.") != string::npos) {
        return false;
    } else if (stof(str) <= 0.0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

bool validateQuantity(const string& str) {
    if (all_of(str.begin(), str.end(), ::isdigit)) {
        if (stoi(str) < 1) {                                   
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

int main() {
    
    const float     NYTAX       = .0875;
    string          p;
    string          q;
    float           price       = -1;
    int             quantity    = -1;
    float           subTotal;
    float           total;

    cout << "enter price: ";
    while (price == -1) {
        cin >> p;
        if (!(validatePrice(p))) {
            cout << "error, try a positive number.\n";
            cout << "enter price: ";
        } else {
            price = stof(p);
        }
    }

    cout << "enter quantity: ";
    while (quantity == -1) {
        cin >> q;
        if (!(validateQuantity(q))) {
            cout << "error, try a positive whole number.\n";
            cout << "enter quantity: ";
        } else {
            quantity = stoi(q);
        }
    }
    
    subTotal = price * quantity;
    total = (round(subTotal + (subTotal * NYTAX)) * 100) / 100;
    cout << "Your total is " << total;
}
```

My problem is twofold. Should I type in "3.00 d" for price, the console prints this:

```
enter quantity: error, try a positive whole number
enter quantity:
```

"3.00 d" has a space and an alphabetical character, so str.find_first_not_of() should return 5. Thus my if condition in validatePrice() should evaluate to false, no?
Part two to this issue is that validateQuantity() is called even though the console should be waiting for me to enter quantity first. This only happens when I mess up the price.

Any other amendments to my code (best practices, simplify) would be appreciated.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to include the suggestions you have received in answers: a new reader would see the updated question and not find the problem, and the answers wouldn't make sense. For example, you have got an answer suggesting to avoid `cin << string`, but after your edit you aren't using it. I'm rolling back your question to its original form.

Comment: Apologies, that was a copy+paste mistake on my part. I had meant to remove redundancy in my code that had nothing to do with cin, but rather the use of comparison operators in my functions. It wasn't needed, and I feared I'd confuse newbies like me reading my question. I must've pasted the entirety of my revision thanks to Bill.

Comment: No problem! If you make sure that you don't invalidate the answer, you can do it again if you want. I'm not sure it would be very useful at this point, but if you want, feel free to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::cin << string` by default reads up to the first whitespace. Note that if you print `str` inside `validatePrice()`, it won't be the full input you specified.

You should use [`std::getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead to read an entire line.

Comment: Thank you. All that needed to be done was switch out cin for getline as you said. Are there situations you'd want to use cin over getline?

Comment: @SharifMa: It all depends on how complicated your life is. If you know the input will be well-formed, std::cin can make your code simpler to read, since it can directly read floats or ints. But as you can see here, adding error checking can be quite difficult.